# Swift short syntax of execution

Tags: swift

I am looking for the way to write short syntax.

For instance. In JS, PHP and etc.

```
var a = 1 ;

function Foo ()-> void {}

a && Foo() ;
```

if a exists, run Foo.

a and Foo itself already mean exist or not, the syntax is away better looks....

However, in Swift, the typing checking is kinda of tough.

```
var a = 1 ;

func Foo ()-> Foid {} ;

a && Foo();
```

will generate neither are Bool returning error.

```
a != nil && Foo() ;
```

this can resolve and variable condition, but what if the better bypass for the function condition? I just dont want to write something like

```
if( a != nil ) { Foo() } ;
```

Yet what is the better syntax for Not Exist?

```
if ( !a ) or !a //is easy and better looks...
```

I found not similar thing in swift...

```
if( a == nil ) // will throws error when its not Optional Typing.

guard var b = xxx else {} // simply for Exist and very long syntax.
```

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Swift is not about writing _short_ code. It's about writing _readable_ code.

Comment: Its readable even in shorter syntax....Readable or not I believe its base on design and naming

Comment: You said `if( a == nil )` will throw error when it's not Optional type, but you don't seem to understand _why_. It throws error exactly because `a` cannot be `nil` (or in your words, not exist) . And I am still confused about exactly what you are asking. Are you looking for a shorter syntax for `f( a != nil ) { Foo() }`?

Comment: What do you mean by "a exists"? Do you mean "a is not 0" or "a is not nil"?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. This seems to just be a comment that you don't like Swift's type system. You're free to feel that way. You may prefer ObjC or JavaScript, which are much looser about type coercion (and there are numerous bugs that causes that Swift avoids). "I don't like to write Swift" is not really a question. What are you really asking here? Perhaps an actual example of problematic code would be helpful rather than an over-simplified example. (Though in the Swift world, `guard let ...` is not usually considered "very long syntax," so there just may be no answer you like.)

Comment: To be clear, in your example `a` is inferred to be a mutable `Int`. It's not an `Int?` (`Optional<Int>`), **so it can't possibly be `nil`** (a.k.a. `Optional<Int>.none`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by other contributors, Swift emphasizes readability and thus, explicit syntax. It would be sacrilege for the Swift standard library to support Python-style [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html).

That being said, Swift’s extensibility allows us to implement such functionality ourselves—*if we really want to*.

```swift
prefix func !<T>(value: T) -> Bool {
    switch T.self {
    case is Bool.Type:
        return value as! Bool
    default:
        guard Double(String(describing: value)) != 0
            else { return false }

        return true
    }
}

prefix func !<T>(value: T?) -> Bool {
    guard let unwrappedValue = value
        else { return false }

    return !unwrappedValue
}

var a = 1

func foo() -> Void { }

!a && !foo()
```

Or even define our own [custom operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#custom-operators):

```swift
prefix operator ✋

prefix func ✋<T>(value: T) -> Bool {
    /// Same body as the previous example.
}

prefix func ✋<T>(value: T?) -> Bool {
    guard let unwrappedValue = value
        else { return false }

    return ✋unwrappedValue
}

var a = 1

func foo() -> Void { }

✋a && ✋foo()
```

Comment: Hey Chris, nice post. I think you should emphasize the "this is batshit crazy theory crafting, don't do this" aspect, but it's interesting overall. BTW you can use `case let b as Bool` to both type-check and cast in one shot, to avoid the need for `is Bool.Type ... as! Bool`

Comment: Chris, You are Brilliant!!

Comment: Alexander, maybe we can improve this with generic and etc, make it better and reasonable. The whole thing is not checking undefined or nil, its about a shorter syntax.

Comment: @Micah What syntax exactly are you trying to shorten?

Comment: @Alexander There are alot, with prefix infix operators, I already made a lot of extended func. Yet, for your concerns, try and catch cloud prevent runtime errors. There only one thing I cannt found solution now, that is Pass function argument dynamically -> "Apply" arguments. This seem like its impossible in Swift.

Comment: @Micah I really didn't understand any of that

Answer (score 2):

The expectations you've developed from dynamic languages like PHP and JS (and Ruby, Python for that matter) are almost universally inapplicable to static languages like Swift.

Swift is a statically compiled language. If you reference a variable that doesn't exist, it's not legal Swift code, and the compiler will fail your build. Given that, the question of "how do I check if a variable is undefined?" is completely moot in Swift. If you have a successfully compiling program that references a variable `a`, then `a` exists. There's absolutely no reason for a check, and so a mechanism for it doesn't even exist.

## Static vs Dynamic typing

Static type systems are like mathematical proof systems. They produce rigerous proofs that certain aspects of your program are valid. This has trade-offs. The rigidity buys you many guarantees. For example, you'll never have a valid Swift program where you accidentally pass an `Int` where a `Bool` is expected. The static type system makes that class of error literally impossible, so it's not something you have to remember to check for yourself.

On the other hand, many truths are easier to intuit than to prove. Thus, there's great utility in scripting and dynamic languages, because they don't demand the rigorous proofs of your claims that static languages require. On the down side, their type systems "do" much less. For example, JS happily lets you reference an undefined variable. To remedy this, JS provides a way for you to do a run-time check to see whether a variable is defined or not. But this isn't a problem Swift has, so the "solution" is absent.

## When static typing is too hard

Swift actually takes a middle ground position. If you find yourself with a statement that's obviously true, but hard to prove to the compiler, various "escape hatches" exist that allow you to leave the safety of the type system, and go into dynamic land. For example, if you look at an `IBOutlet`, and see that it's connected to an element in a storyboard, you can intuitively be sure that the `IBOutlet` is not `nil`. But that's not something you can prove to the compiler, and hence when you see implicitly unwrapped optionals being used for `IBOutlet`s.

Implicitly unwrapped optionals are one such "escape hatch". The `Any` type is another, as is `unsafeBitcast(_:to:)`, `withoutActuallyEscaping(_:)`, `as!`, `try!`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Swift takes type safety very seriously. Unlike C or JS we can not use anything that doesn't resolve to Bool value type in If statement in Swift. So there won't be a short hand for that(at-least that I know of). Regarding below code

```
 if( a == nil ) // will throws error when its not Optional Typing.
```

Swift doesn't allow you to set nil to non optional types. So there is no need to check for nil. By the way both Obj-C and Swift use verbose syntax, we need to get use to that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are trying to force Swift to work in a way that you are used to with other languages like JavaScript or PHP, as you say in your comment.  There are a few reasons why your code won't compile, but it mainly falls on the fact that Swift doesn't do the same truthy and falsy stuff JS does.

```
var a = 1
if a {
  print("won't compile")
}
//'Int' is not convertible to 'Bool'
```

In Swift it's better to use an actual Bool value if that's what it's supposed to be, or if it's truly supposed to be an Int you're just going to have to check the value

```
var a = true
if a {
  print("this compiles")
}
```

or

```
var a = 1
if a > 0 {
  print("this compiles too")
}
```

Swift really isn't meant to be as loose as JS, so you should just embrace that and take advantage of the safety and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way most similar to what you designed.

You may have to set the type of a to Int?:

```
  var a: Int? = 1
  func foo ()-> Void {}
  a.map{_ in foo()}
```